# Problem hanging ceiling lamp with cord set (from Ikea)

Tags: ceiling, lamp

Trying to hang a ceiling lamp and I can't figure it out.

It's the type where you hook the connector to the ceiling, then push the "cup" (which conceals all the wiring) up to the ceiling.

But there doesn't seem to be a way of fixing the cup to the ceiling, it always dangles by about a centimetre or two. The instructions (pictures only) seem to suggest that you simply have to push it up and I suppose the tension in the cord maybe holds it in place, but it always slides down a little bit.

A suggestion I received from their [Ikea's] telephone help line was that maybe amount of cord coiled up inside the cup was too much and was pushing it out (and I should shorten the cord), but I've even tried pulling it all out so there is virtually no wire left inside, with the same results.

I've tried to diagram my problem below... The blue cup should be against the ceiling, but I can't see any way of holding it in place except the grip the cup has on the cord but that doesn't seem to be strong enough.
[image: Diagram of problem]

**Update**

I happened to be in Ikea again a few weeks ago, and noted that not even *they* can hang the things properly!

[image]

[image]

Comment: FYI mentioned Ikea because I bought several different ones in the same shop and they all seem to use the same method to connect to the ceiling...

Comment: For a [lifehacks.se] type of solution, I guess you could use a few layers of tape wrapped around the cable just below the "cup" to increase the cable diameter and thus tension where it's needed?

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try later. Just need to get red tape so it's not unsightly but maybe some other kind of stop under the cap would do the trick as an alternative. BTW what I did in the end was cut the cable to size which improved things (I'm not sure how as pulling all the cable out didn't help at all) but still isn't perfect and comes loose every time someone touches the lamp...

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar Ikea fixture, but it came with a metal sleeve that tightens with a screw--this part sits below the cap, but this light has a rod (rigid, not the cord itself) for this sleeve to work on.

[image]

Did you buy it new? If for some reason you didn't have the instructions and therefore couldn't verify if a piece was missing, you can find those here: http://www.ikea.com/ms/en_US/customer_service/assembly_instructions.html I know you can order replacement parts from Ikea, at least if what you need hasn't been discontinued.

Assuming you have the instructions and all the pieces, I think your best bet would be finding a rubber O-ring (or several) which match the cord diameter, and sliding those up to keep the cap up....or using a twist-tie painted to match the cord. Once you have the cap up reasonably flush with the ceiling, you could use clear silicone caulk around the rim of the cup, which can easily be peeled away later if you're renting.

Finally, is the hook all the way in? Perhaps screwing it up further into the ceiling would make the cap go higher.

Best of luck!

Comment: Got it new and have instructions - there was no part missing and the instructions don't mention about a piece similar to the screw-in sleeve you have. The hook is all the way in, but putting it up further would make no difference (if it was possible) because the hook itself is not actually attached to the cap.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, it was about 2 in the morning :P