# Shortening a pendant lamp cord without cutting it

Tags: electrical, lamp

I need to install a pendant lamp that has a cord that is way too long for the room it's being installed in. The lamp has a canopy (I believe that is the correct term in English; the small cup screwed against the ceiling which covers the hook on which the lamp is suspended).

The cord of the lamp is too long. I'm supposed to adjust the cord to proper length and then stuff the extra cord inside the canopy. However, this is quite difficult since the extra length is quite long. Would it be possible to tie some kind of knot to the cord that would compress it to a smaller volume? Would tying a tight knot to an electrical cord possibly damage it? Or are there any other methods that I could use to fit the extra cord inside the canopy? Cutting the cord is not really an option here.

The type of lamp I'm talking about is the same as in this question:

[Problem hanging ceiling lamp with cord set (from Ikea)](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/63348/problem-hanging-ceiling-lamp-with-cord-set-from-ikea)

Comment: i would tie a figure 8 follow through in the bite; uses lots of cord, avoids locking knots. some knots could, in theory, damage the wiring if pulled tight. Its probably not an issue; ikea tends to sell good quality electrical; i'd be more concerned on a cheap no-name lamp. you can wrap a carribeaner to remove slack without damaging anything; we used to do that with climbing webbing that can't get dirty or kinked...

Comment: @dandavis Thanks, how exactly would I use a caribeaner in this situation?

Comment: you just open it and wind the cord around it, like you're wrapping a pipe, around the bends, and then close it to stop it unwinding.