# Pendant light cord too long

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, ceiling, old-house

How would you shorten a pendant lamp's electrical cable? It's a USA home from the 1920s.

The question has been asked [before](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/144615/102152), but wrapping an electrical cable around a metal caribeaner seems dangerous.

[image: Context image]
[image: Ceiling hole]

Comment: Could you not disconnect it, and trim the wire (the white cable too), and reattach it to the electrical box?

Comment: @JCrosby -- that's an answer.

Comment: It *would* be an answer if there *was* an electrical box!  Photo shows an adapter yoke screwed into ceiling lath, and wire nuts on cable of unknown type. - OP need to do more than just safely shorten the pendant wire.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri, what else do you believe I'd need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This installation needs a junction box. Electrical ordinances require that all power connections be made inside an accessible protective box.

In the USA your governing code will be your state's adoption or enhancement of some edition of the [NEC](https://www.nfpa.org/NEC). Other places in the civilized world will have similar ordinances. This is why I asked where you are.

If you are handy with detail carpentry, you may be able to do this job yourself, but if you are not confident and comfortable, you should hire a handyman or even an electrician. Ask for someone who can do "old work" "wiring repair".

Comment: Good catch on the lack of box. The OP should note that the insulation on knob and tube wiring is very fragile, and so adding a junction box can be a challenge. Perhaps this is the place for a pro...